# Rewarded Video Ads listner for ad application is installed or not in user device

Tags: android, admob, rewardedvideoad

I have implemented **Rewarded Video Ads** on my android application. But I don't know **how to get whether a user has installed an application which is shown on video ad?**. Based on installation I have to give points. Any suggestion how to identify this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The content of the ad that's shown to the user is considered private, so publishers don't have access to it. Rewards should be given to the user when the reward callback is invoked by the Mobile Ads SDK.